# Android retrieve contact name always returns false

Tags: android, contacts

I am trying to check whether given name is in phone contact or not, but it always returns false, i cant figure out what mistake i have done

```
public boolean ContactNotFound(String no, String name) {
    if (no != null) {
        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(name));
        String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID,
                PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
        Cursor cur = con.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,
                mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);

        LogUtil.d("Count -->" + cur.getCount());

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            try {
                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    return true;
                }
            } finally {
                if (cur != null)
                    cur.close();
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Kindly help me to figure out the issue

Comment: Where r u comparing the name?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to save all your contact names in arraylist temporarily and then check name using `arrayList.contains(name)` method

Comment: i have used   PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI so there is no need of comparing right? am i wrong?